# window.bind() similar functionality using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set the context of a function and pass it as a callback. For that I am doing this.

```
myController.myService.validateToken(param)
    .then( myController.myService.getToken.bind( myController.myService ) );
```

**myController.myService.getToken.bind( myController.myService )**

But I am not sure whether it's the right approach or not?

Does Angular provide similar functionality as `bind()`?

Comment: Just try it and see if it works.

Comment: Why should angular implement existing bind?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/function/angular.bind

Comment: @simon what javascript frameworks don't already wrap existing keywords :P

Comment: @dfsq: it works fine. no issue on that. But thing is bind() is the window's method. I think I should not use directly. Either I need to use it by $window.bind() or similar function provided by angular.

Comment: @ShaojiangCai: I think this is what I am looking for. Thanks!!. Let me try this.

Comment: @Alp bind is not a window method, it's a method of Function prototype. And yes, you **should** use it instead of `angular.bind` (unnecessary overhead), unless you support IE8.

Comment: @dfsq Yes you are right!! its a Function prototype. But Do you really think I should use it instead of angular.bind, if so then why angular is giving similar thing?

Comment: It's a browser native thing, and it is going to be way performant compared to custom implementation. Why Angular provides it? It's a polyfill for IE8 which doesn't support it. So If your application needs to work in IE8 then you should use `angular.bind`. Otherwise using native method makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks. I understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [angular.bind](http://%20code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/function/angular.bind), which is defined in AngularJS 1.4.1 (Line 1146) as:

```
function bind(self, fn) {
  var curryArgs = arguments.length > 2 ? sliceArgs(arguments, 2) : [];
  if (isFunction(fn) && !(fn instanceof RegExp)) {
    return curryArgs.length
      ? function() {
          return arguments.length
            ? fn.apply(self, concat(curryArgs, arguments, 0))
            : fn.apply(self, curryArgs);
        }
      : function() {
          return arguments.length
            ? fn.apply(self, arguments)
            : fn.call(self);
        };
  } else {
    // in IE, native methods are not functions so they cannot be bound (note: they don't need to be)
    return fn;
  }
}
```

So the usage should be like:

```
var context, fn, args;
angular.bind(context, fn, args);
```

Comment: Wha I made in my case is
myController.myService.validateToken(param)
    .then(angular.bind(myController.myService,  myController.myService.getToken );